# c++ converting int to char + add leading zeros to char

Tags: c++, type-conversion, leading-zero

I got numbers from 0 to 999. How can I achieve the following

```
int i = 123;//possible values 0-999
char i_char[3] = /*do conversion of int i to char and add 3 leading zeros*/
```

Example(s): `i_char` shall look like `"001"` for `i=1`, `"011"` for `i=11` or `"101"` for `i=101`

Comment: You want a `std::string`, not a `char`.

Comment: Because `char` can only hold one single letter.

Comment: what about an array of chars?

Comment: Your array needs to be of size 4, since any sequence of `char`s in C is always terminated by a null char `\0`

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: He is looking for a zpad function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are looking for sprintf, or perhaps printf.

```
int i = 123;
char str[10];
sprintf(str, "%03d", i);
```

Comment: **−1** Using type unsafe `sprintf` is very ungood advice to a newbie. Ditto for the use of a raw array.

Comment: if you recommend this at least recommend `snprintf`

Answer (score 5):

Use a `std::ostringstream` with `std::setfill()` and `std::setw()`, eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int i = ...;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << i;
std::string s = oss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you tagged the question with `c++` here is a quick solution using `std::string` and `std::to_string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
   int i = 1;
   std::string s = std::to_string(i);

   if ( s.size() < 3 )
       s = std::string(3 - s.size(), '0') + s;

   std::cout << s << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

For `i=1` it will output: `001`.

Comment: Please test with `int i = 12345`. Surprise?

Comment: Well, he can check if `s.size() < 3`. Let me edit it.